# Why can IEnumerable<T> do this but List<T> cannot?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

When I have a class `Car` that implements `ICar` and I have a `List<Car>` why is it possible to call a method expecting `IEnumerable<ICar>` but neither `IList<ICar>` nor `List<ICar>`?

`IList<T>` is derived from `IEnumerable<T>` and `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

So if I can assign `List<Car>` to an `IEnumerable<ICar>` because the compiler figures out that `Car` is an `ICar` why doesn't it work further down the inheritance / implementation chain?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var fords = new List<Ford>() { new Ford("T") };

        IEnumerableOfICar(fords);
        IListOfICar(fords); //error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'List<Ford>' to 'IList<ICar>'
        ListOfICar(fords); //error CS1503
        IEnumerableOfCar(fords);
        IListOfCar(fords); //error CS1503
        ListOfCar(fords); //error CS1503
        IEnumerableOfFord(fords);
        IListOfFord(fords);
        ListOfFord(fords);
    }

    private static void IEnumerableOfICar(IEnumerable<ICar> cars)
    {
        foreach (var car in cars)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(car.Model);
        }
    }

    private static void IListOfICar(IList<ICar> cars)
    {
        IEnumerableOfICar(cars);
    }

    private static void ListOfICar(List<ICar> cars)
    {
        IEnumerableOfICar(cars);
    }

    private static void IEnumerableOfCar(IEnumerable<Car> cars)
    {
        IEnumerableOfICar(cars);
    }

    private static void IListOfCar(IList<Car> cars)
    {
        IEnumerableOfICar(cars);
        IListOfICar(cars); //error CS1503
        ListOfICar(cars); //error CS1503
    }

    private static void ListOfCar(List<Car> cars)
    {
        IEnumerableOfICar(cars);
        IListOfICar(cars); //error CS1503
        ListOfICar(cars); //error CS1503
    }

    private static void IEnumerableOfFord(IEnumerable<Ford> cars)
    {
        IEnumerableOfICar(cars);
        IEnumerableOfCar(cars);
    }

    private static void IListOfFord(IList<Ford> fords)
    {
        IEnumerableOfICar(fords);
        IEnumerableOfCar(fords);
        IListOfICar(fords); //error CS1503
        IListOfCar(fords); //error CS1503
    }

    private static void ListOfFord(List<Ford> fords)
    {
        IEnumerableOfICar(fords);
        IEnumerableOfCar(fords);
        IListOfICar(fords); //error CS1503
        ListOfICar(fords); //error CS1503
        IListOfCar(fords); //error CS1503
        ListOfCar(fords); //error CS1503
    }
}

internal interface ICar
{
    string Model { get; }
}

internal abstract class Car : ICar
{
    public string Model { get; }

    protected Car(string model) => this.Model = model;
}

internal class Ford : Car
{
    public Ford(string model) : base(model) { }
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant because it only produces data.  `IList<T>` is invariant because you can both get data out and also put new data in.

Comment: imagine that you have `abstract class Sedan : ICar` and also `abstract class Convertible : ICar`.  You can put a `Corolla` into a `List<Sedan >` and into a `List<ICar>` but not into a `List<Convertible>`.  That means `List<Convertible>` is not compatible with `List<ICar>`.